# ArgumentNullException when invoking RenderComponent with Action

Tags: razor-components, bunit

I am trying to test a custom Razor component with an EventBack parameter:

```
@code {
  [Parameter]
  public EventCallback OnClick { get; set; }
}
```

I am using bUnit with xUnit to try to test EventCallback.  Here's my test method:

```
public void TestOnClickEvent()
{
  void TestOnClick()
  {
    Assert.True(true);
  }

  IRenderedComponent<CSInput> component = 
    RenderComponent<CSInput>(
      builder => builder.Add(
        instanceOfCSInput => instanceOfCSInput.OnClick,
        TestOnClick));

  component.Find("input").Click();
}
```

When I tried to run the test, I get an ArgumentNullException from RenderComponent(), but I have no idea what could it be since everything is all in lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the location function is the issue.  I replace the call to the local function with another lambda and it works!

```
IRenderedComponent<CSInput> component = 
    RenderComponent<CSInput>(
      builder => builder.Add(
        instanceOfCSInput => instanceOfCSInput.OnClick,
        () => Assert.True(true)));
```